# Rendering a high-fps gif from a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, gif

I've been at this for about an hour. I've extracted the frames from my clip and rendered the frames to a mp4 with no problem. The mp4 plays exactly like how I'd like my gif to play, but when using `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 test.gif` it ends up as a slow, low-bitrate gif that plays at around half the framerate of what I'd like it to. I'm not sure if the encoding is dropping frames as a result of a default option, or what, but I'd like the help of someone more well-versed in ffmpeg. I've looked at other threads and can't quite figure out what to do. Thanks.

Comment: Check out this blog post https://medium.com/@colten_jackson/doing-the-gif-thing-on-debian-82b9760a8483

Comment: Share full log for your command